# Можно ли применять const_cast к разыменованному const_iterator?

Tags: c++, const-cast

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
void function(std::list<Type>::const_iterator iterator)
{
    // iterator гарантированно указывает на корректный элемент.
    Type& type = const_cast<Type&>(*iterator);
    type.field = 0;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, является ли данный код законным с точки зрения `Стандарта`?

Comment: Как бы это сказать... `const_iterator` и `const iterator` - это две большие разницы...

Comment: @Harry, при разыменовании `iterator` мы получаем `const Type&`. Законно ли это преобразовать в `Type&` при помощи `const_cast`, при условии, что исходный объект - не константный.

Comment: ну почему бы нет?   Это снятие с обьекта констант квалификатора

Comment: Даже если является валидным вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: Единтсвенный подводный камень - обращение к константынм данным может породить неопределенное поведение: `const int array[3]={1,2,3}; const_cast<int&>(* std::cbegin(array) ) = 3; `.

Comment: @Chorkov, да, это мне известно.